# limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

The website keeps timing out, I assume because of the large number of "internal redirects" it is attempting.

How should this be fixed?

Hundreds of lines on the SSL error log show:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: What URL is being requested?

Comment: Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: URL requested is: referer: https://www.tacwise.com/spare-parts-store/

Comment: Yes i do believe i have access to the server config

Comment: What is "referer:" referring to in your comment? (The "referer" is the URL that the user is coming from, not the URL that is requested?) If you have access to the server config then you should set `LogLevel debug` (as the error msg states), restart Apache and recheck the error log when getting this error to see the _backtrace_. The "backtrace" should show you exactly what these "internal redirects" are. You appear to have a WordPress _multisite_ setup - can you summarise how this is configured on your server and the basic directory structure?